# Reversible Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Be S = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and a measure ν in S with the weights {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, respectively.

Determine an irreducible stochastic matrix P in S with a circular structure as in picture below, and which are in detailed balance with ν.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqtMk.png

I try creating a system of linear equations bases on this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb7Zc.png

but, aways i have negative values....

Comment: Since you are looking for detailed balance with $v$, that immediately tells you what $c$ is in terms of $a$, what $e$ is in terms of $d$, and what every element in the bottom left is in terms of its mirror pair.  Then the condition that you have a stochastic matrix will give you five equations in those 5 variables. However, without seeing your work and what equations you are setting up to solve, it's impossible to say where your mistake is and why you are getting negative numbers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer,.
Here are the equations using wolfram alpha:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRr3U.png  
could you help me find the error?

Answer (score 0):

A reversible $P$ will occur when you assign each (undirected) edge in your "circular structure" a weight $w(i,j)$ ($i$ and $j$ the endpoints of the edge connecting them; undirected implying that $w(i,j) = w(j,i)$.) To achieve $\nu$ as reversibility measure you need to choose those 5 edge-weights so that the total weight of edges emanating from $i$ is $\nu(i)$, for each $i$. This yields a system of 5 linear equations in the 5 unknown edge-weights (not the 10 of your second image).

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer,.
Here are the equations using wolfram alpha:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRr3U.png  
could you help me find the error?

Comment: As I said, for a reversible $P$, there are but 5 weights. Label them 
$$
a=w(1,2), b=w(2,3), c=w(3,4), d=w(4,5), e = w(5,1).
$$
 The linear system is then: 
$$
e+a=1, a+b=2, b+c=3, c+d=4, d+e=5.
$$ 
(And you want $a,b,c,d,e$ to be $>0$, for the sake of irreducibility.)

Comment: thx for the help, but the linear system that you proposed also returns negative values, and greater than 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5XCd.png

Comment: Which tells me that the given $\nu$ isn't feasible.  Or maybe you had something else in mind than reversibility with "detailed balance"?

Comment: Yes, i guess too...thx for the Help!